# torrent download problem (xdg-open)

Tags: 16.04, firefox, chromium, transmission

I've been a happy Ubuntu 16.04 user for some time now.
Recently I experienced a problem when downloading torrent.
Before everything went smooth (download torrent - open with transmission - and start downloading).
However when I click a torrent download link now - chrome or firefox ask me the pop-up question 'open xdg-open'. When I click yes - transmission opens and there is no file to download. Very strange and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Someone any experience?

Thanks a lot!